# Interact with podman docker via socket in Redhat 9

Tags: docker, redhat, podman

I'm trying to migrate one of my dev boxes over from centos 8 to RHEL9. I rely heavily on docker and noticed when I tried to run a docker command on the RHEL box it installed podman-docker. This seemed to go smoothly; I was able to pull an image, launch, build, commit a new version without problem using the docker commands I knew already.

The problem I have encountered though is I can't seem to interact with it via the docker socket (which seems to be a link to the podman one).

If I run the docker command:

```
[@rhel9 ~]$ docker images
Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg.
REPOSITORY             TAG              IMAGE ID      CREATED      SIZE
docker.io/redhat/ubi9  dev_image        de371523ca26  6 hours ago  805 MB
docker.io/redhat/ubi9  latest           9ad46cd10362  6 days ago   230 MB
```

it has my images listed as expected. I should be able to also run:

```
[@rhel9 ~]$ curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost/images/json | jq .
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     3  100     3    0     0     55      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    55
[]
```

but as you can see, nothing is coming back. The socket is up and running as I can ping it without issue:

```
[@rhel9 ~]$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/_ping
OK
```

I also tried the curl commands using the podman socket directly but it had the same results. Is there something I am missing or a trick to getting it to work so that I can interact with docker/podman via the socket?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem although I'm not entirely sure how the scenario came about. I was looking through the output of `docker info` and `podman info` and noticed that they both had the remote socket set as:

```
remoteSocket:
    exists: true
    path: /run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock
```

rather than `/run/podman/podman.sock` which is where I thought it was (this socket does actually exist on my machine). Looking at the systemd file for `podman.socket` I can see that the socket was specified as `%t/podman/podman.sock` and checking the man page for `podman-system-service` it specified the rootless socket as `unix://$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/podman/podman.sock` (where my `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000`.

To get it all working with my software I just needed to make sure the `DOCKER_HOST` env variable was correctly set e.g. `export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock`

Comment: after setting this env, I am getting "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"

Answer (score 6):

Podman isn't implemented using a client/server model like Docker. By default there is no socket, because there's no equivalent to the docker daemon. Podman does provide a compatibility interface that you can use by enabling the `podman.socket` unit:

```
$ systemctl enable --now podman.socket
```

This exposes a Unix socket at `/run/podman/podman.sock` that responds to Docker API commands. But!

The socket connects you to `podman` running as *root*, whereas you've been running `podman` as a non-root user: so you won't see the same list of images, containers, networks, etc.

---

Some random notes:

- Podman by default runs "rootless": you can run it as an unprivileged user, and all of its storage, metadata, etc, is stored in your home directory.
- You can *also* run Podman as `root`, in which case the behavior is more like Docker.
- If you enable the podman socket, you can replace `podman-docker` with the actual Docker client (and use things like `docker-compose`), although I have run into occasional issues with this. Mostly I just use podman, and run docker engine in a VM). You will need to configure Docker to look at the podman socket in `/run/podman/podman.sock`.

---

I have `podman.socket` enabled on my system, so this works:

```
$ curl --unix-socket /run/podman/podman.sock -H 'content-type: application/json' http://localhost/_ping
OK
```

Or:

```
$ curl --unix-socket /run/podman/podman.sock -H 'content-type: application/json' -sf http://localhost/containers/json | jq
[
  {
    "Id": "f0d9a880c45bb5857b24f46bcb6eeeca162eb68d574c8ba16c4a03703c2d60f4",
    "Names": [
      "/sleeper"
    ],
    "Image": "docker.io/library/alpine:latest",
    "ImageID": "14119a10abf4669e8cdbdff324a9f9605d99697215a0d21c360fe8dfa8471bab",
    "Command": "sleep inf",
    "Created": 1655418914,
    "Ports": [],
    "Labels": {},
    "State": "running",
    "Status": "Up 3 days",
    "NetworkSettings": {
      "Networks": {
        "podman": {
          "IPAMConfig": null,
          "Links": null,
          "Aliases": null,
          "NetworkID": "podman",
          "EndpointID": "",
          "Gateway": "10.88.0.1",
          "IPAddress": "10.88.0.2",
          "IPPrefixLen": 16,
          "IPv6Gateway": "",
          "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
          "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
          "MacAddress": "06:55:82:1b:1a:41",
          "DriverOpts": null
        }
      }
    },
    "Mounts": null,
    "Name": "",
    "Config": null,
    "NetworkingConfig": null,
    "Platform": null,
    "AdjustCPUShares": false
  }
]
```

Comment: I had the socket already running and was able to ping it without issue (see output in the question) as non root user. The problem seemed to be there was more than one socket and I was interacting with the wrong one.

Comment: This is not entirely true, it seems to be old info from before podman conformed to the Docker API. Now it runs a socket for rootless users at /run/user/<USERID>

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use

```
systemctl enable --now podman.socket
```

to create `/var/run/podman/podman.sock`, because you don't have the root account, you can use

```
systemctl --user enable --now podman.socket
```

to create `/var/run/user/${UID}/podman/podman.sock` which is owned by your current user. Keep in mind that each user (as well as the root user) sees their own podman environment, with different images and different running containers.

If you don't have systemd available, then use

```
podman system service --time=0 unix:///tmp/podman.sock &
```

which runs podman in the background (through &) and creates the socket at the given location. Maybe run this with sudo, depending on what you want to do exactly.